# How to get gsettings-desktop-schemas >= 3.23.3 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, gnome

I want to compile the `gnome-settings-daemon` with a modified DPI constant. For that I've cloned the [repository](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon), applied the change and created a `configure` script through `autogen.sh`.

When I tried to execute `configure`, it complained about a few unmet dependencies, specifically `gsettings-desktop-schemas >= 3.23.3`.

To remedy that, I've tried installing `gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev` from `apt`. That only gave me the version `3.18.1`, which [seems to be](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gsettings-desktop-schemas) the main release for Xenial (16.04).

How can I install the required version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it wrong.

You should download xenial's version:

1. Get its build-dependencies with 
   `sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-settings-daemon`
2. Get its source `sudo apt-get source gnome-settings-daemon`
3. Patch the source (yours "applied the change")
4. Change configure options and run `./configure ...`
5. Create custom deb-package with these options.
6. Install self-compiled custom package.

I hope you got idea.

Comment: Thanks, nice one. I'd suggest you to add the steps 5 and 6 for people like me who struggle to figure out how it's done :)
I ran `sudo make` and `sudo checkinstall` (`checkinstall` needs to be installed separately through `apt`)